# Diskrepanz Antwort ohne Upvote der Frage

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Eine Frage, die es wert ist, beantwortet zu werden, sollte im Normalfall auch aufgewertet werden.

Vielleicht etwas klarer formuliert: Wenn man eine Frage beantwortet (nicht nur theoretisch für Wert befindet...), sollte man sie hochwerten. Ausnahmen, etwa wenn der Inhalt nur mit Mühe erschließbar war, können natürlich bestehen. Aber wieso sollte man schlechte Fragen beantworten?

Fragen, die man deplatziert findet, sollte man zur Schließung vorschlagen, Themen, zu denen man sich gar nicht auskennt, nicht beantworten und Fragen, die  einem als reine Abwälzung von Arbeit auf Andere (no research) erscheinen bzw. als nicht nützlich sollte man abwerten aber nicht beantworten.

Wie kann man eine Frage beantworten, ohne sie aufzuwerten? Das ist eine rhetorische Frage; es gibt die Fälle. Die Frage kann unklar gestellt sein, aber es kann zu erraten sein, was die eigentliche Frage ist usw. - das kommt vor, aber selten.

Im Regelfall sollte man eine Frage, die man einer Antwort würdig findet, auch aufwerten.

Meine Anregung ist: Wir sollten Teilnehmer, die schon länger dabei sind (>= 1k Rep.) sporadisch fragen, wieso sie eine Frage beantworten aber nicht hochwerten. Nicht ständig, aber so, dass häufige Leser früher oder später darüber nachdenken und vielleicht auch auf die Idee kommen, Fragen positiv zu bewerten, natürlich nur, wenn die Frage keine offensichtlichen Schwächen aufweist.

#### Update

In letzter Zeit mehren sich die Fälle, in denen Neulinge die Antwortfunktion zum Bedanken missbrauchen, weil ihnen die Reputation fehlt, Antworten aufzuwerten. Insbes. wenn jmd. noch keine Aufwertprivilegien genießt, sollte man die Frage, die man beantwortet, ruhig großzügig uppen.

Später kann man dannn ja wieder wählerischer werden.

Comment: Yo. Ebenso umgekehrt: *nicht* beantworten, wenn man sich zum upvoten nicht aufraffen kann?

Comment: Das ist mir auch aufgefallen, aber wie ist das umsetzbar? Manchmal hat eine Frage 1 upvote, 0 downvotes, und 3 Antworten. Soll man dann jeden fragen?

Comment: @infinitezero nein, ich denke, Rückfragen kann man nur dann, solange 1 Antwort und 0 (up)votes.

Comment: @infinitezero: Ähnlich wie Shegit Brahm schreibt: Man kann nur nachfragen, solange es noch kein Upvote gibt und wenn man die Reputation hat zu prüfen, ob es nicht vielleicht 2 Up- und 2 Downvotes gibt, die sich neutralisiert haben. Das ist aber kein Problem, weil es nur um sporadische Erinnerungen geht, nicht um flächendeckende Ermahnungen.

Comment: Man kann auch Fragen beantworten, die man nicht so super findet. Hier ist ja nicht viel los.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Super finden ist kein Kriterium für Upvotes, bzw. hinreichend, aber nicht notwendig. "Shows research, is useful & clear".

Comment: Ich bin neu hier, aber in anderen Bereichen dieses Portals werden sogar Fragen, die durchaus Sinn machen, mit Minuspunkten "bestraft" ...

Comment: "Eine Frage, die es wert ist, beantwortet zu werden, sollte im Normalfall auch aufgewertet werden."


Zu welchem Zweck?
Habe ich ein Problem suche zuerst danach, ob es schon eine mehr oder weniger passende Frage gibt und hoffe, dass es dazu auch passende Antworten gibt -- Votes sind mir da egal (bei den Antworten ist es etwas anders).
Abgesehen davon empfinde ich sowohl das Up- und Down-Voten als auch das Schliessen allzuoft als nicht nachvollziehbar bis willkürlich, mich jedenfalls hält es davon ab, Fragen zu stellen.

Comment: Jetzt fängst du auch noch an, anderen zu erklären, wie sie sich hier zu verhalten haben. *...sollte im Normalfall auch aufgewertet werden*? Schön, dass wir jetzt statt *englische Fragen müssen englisch beantwortet werden* unter jeder zweiten Frage eine Ermahnung zum Upvoteverhalten lesen werden.

Comment: @Olafant: Ich weiß nicht was Deinen gereizten Tonfall begünstigt hat. Ich fange hier nicht an anderen zu erklären, wie sie sich zu verhalten haben, sondern habe eine Idee zur Diskussion gestellt, um das Für und Wider zu diskutieren und dabei probehalber die Für-Position eingenommen. Wenn Du von "englische Fragen müssen englisch beantwortet werden"-Posts genervt bist, such bitte die entsprechenden Diskussionen auf Meta und misch das hier nicht dazwischen. Sparbücher mit Genervtguthaben sollte man m.E. nicht anlegen - ich zahl Dir darauf jedenfalls keine Zinsen.

Comment: @user41324: Der Zweck ist es, gute Fragen zu belohnen um so Anreiz zu schaffen, mehr gute Fragen zu stellen. Allgemein wird auf SE oft geklagt, die Fragen würden zu selten hochgewertet (evtl. auch runter~) werden. Dazu finden sich m.W. auf der allgemeinen Metaseite mehr Diskussionen als in unserem kl. Eck.

Answer (score 10):

> Eine Frage, die es wert ist, beantwortet zu werden, sollte im Normalfall auch aufgewertet werden.

Ich stimme dem nicht zu. *Wert* ist eine seltsame Kategorie; ich persönlich beantworte nicht ausschließlich Fragen, die ich einer Antwort *wert* finde. Solche Fragen sind viel zu spärlich gesät. Als Vorbedingung für das Verfassen einer Antwort sehe ich stattdessen die Erwartung, daß die Antwort **nützlich für andere** ist. Viele schlecht gestellte Fragen (keine Recherche, kein Kontext, keine Mühe) geben immer noch Anlaß für solche Antworten; ebenso Fragen, die von falschen Annahmen ausgehen oder Verwirrung stiften.

Ein Beispiel aus der letzten Zeit sind Fragen zum Verb *gefallen*: welche Kasus regiert das Verb, wie erkennt man das Subjekt, usw. Für kompetente Lerner sollte ein Blick ins Wörterbuch ausreichen, um sich diese Fragen selber zu beantworten. Da aber nicht alle Lerner diese Kompetenz haben und, was das wichtigere Argument ist, nicht in allen Sprachen eine Parallele zu deutschen Verben wie *gefallen, gehören, schmecken, fehlen …* existiert, halte ich die Antworten für nützlich.

Comment: Ich hatte auch nicht geschrieben <b>ausschließlich</b> sondern stimme ausdrücklich zu, dass es Fragen gibt, die man einer Antwort wert findet (das ist keine seltsame Kategorie - die Zeit wert, die Du investierst), aber dennoch nicht aufwerten will, Mangelnde Recherche und Kontext kann man mit einem close-vote anmahnen. Ich meine man sollte bei den meisten Fragen, die man beantwortet, erwägen sie auch aufzuwerten - ansonsten wäre ein Kommentar, aus dem sich ergibt, wieso nicht, vielleicht oft sinnvoll.

Comment: @userunknown Sollte man nicht bei allen Fragen, die man liest, erwägen, ob man sie aufwertet?

Comment: Mir ging es darum, dass ich oft Fragen ohne offensichtliche Mängel sah, für die jemand eine Antwort geschrieben, aber die noch niemand aufgewertet hat. Von Ausnahmen abgesehen finde ich das unlogisch und fand, man solle da ab und zu mal nachhaken. Prinzipiell steht es aber jedem frei zu erwägen oder nicht und auch rasche Entscheidungen zu treffen, ohne lange zu erwägen, insbesondere die Entscheidung nicht zu voten kann immer getroffen werden. Wer sich aber schon die Zeit für's Antworten nimmt ...

Comment: @DavidVogt *Sollte man nicht bei allen Fragen, die man liest, erwägen, ob man sie aufwertet?* - Ja, erwägen sollte man das auf jeden Fall, es sind aber Fälle möglich, in denen man sich dann bewusst dagegen entscheidet (s. meine Antwort).

Answer (score 7):

Die Sichtweise, dass eine Frage, die beantwortet wird, im Normalfall auch aufgerwertet werden sollte, kann ich nicht nachvollziehen.

Ich gebe einer Frage vor allem dann einen Upvote, wenn sie [vernünftig gestellt](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) ist und von einem User kommt, der noch nicht über genügend Reputation verfügt, um zu kommentieren oder um aus meiner Sicht ungerechtfertigte Downvotes auszugleichen. Insbesondere, wenn andere Fragen desselben neuen Users wenig Mühe erkennen lassen, sich verständlich auszudrücken oder ein Wörterbuch zu benutzen, halte ich Upvotes guter Fragen für eine günstige Gelegenheit, den respektvollen Umgang mit der Zeit hilfsbereiter User zu würdigen.

Darüber hinaus halte ich Upvotes dann für sinnvoll, wenn ich glaube, dass eine Frage anderen Lernenden weiterhelfen kann, die noch nicht wissen, was eigentlich ihre Frage ist. Die größte Schwierigkeit beim Lernen besteht darin, die richtigen Fragen zu stellen und in den Wirren aller Anfänge ist es oft sehr schwer, diese Fragen zu finden und zu formulieren.

Beides ist davon unabhängig, ob ich eine Frage beantworte oder nicht. Anders herum gibt es auch interessante (oder wenigstens nicht uninteressante) Fragen, die ich für Lernende aber unerheblich finde und andere, die vernünftig gestellt sind, deren Gedankengang ich aber für Quatsch halte. Die kann ich dann auch durchaus ohne Upvote beantworten.

Dem Vorschlag, bei einer Diskrepanz zwischen der Anzahl der Antworten und Upvotes nachzufragen, kann ich nur widersprechen. **Kommentare sind nicht für Diskussionen über *community behavior or site policies* [gedacht](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).** Dafür gibt es meta. Wer selbst hin und wieder in Foren recherchiert, wird vielleicht nachvollziehen können, dass die Kommentare sowohl zu Fragen als auch zu Antworten durchaus sehr nützlich sein können. Ich persönlich finde es aber immer sehr ärgerlich weil zeitraubend, wenn dort dann über Dinge diskutiert wird, die mit der Frage nichts zu tun haben und ich finde, wir sollten uns davor hüten, das hier einreißen zu lassen. Wem es also wirklich um Qualität geht, der sollte m.E. nicht nach den Motiven für gegebene oder unterlassene (jedem freigestellte) Upvotes fragen.

Comment: Dem letzten Absatz kann ich nur zustimmen. Dem im zweiten Absatz geschilderten Verfahren werde ich allerdings nie folgen: Ich finde es sowohl einfacher als auch fairer, die Frage nur nach ihrer Qualität zu bewerten, und die Person des Fragestellers (Reputation, andere Fragen usw.) außer acht zu lassen.

Comment: @DavidVogt Da habe ich mich wahrscheinlich etwas missverständlich ausgedrückt. Es geht mir auch nur um die Qualität der Frage. Insbesondere bei neuen Usern halte ich Upvotes für eine wichtige Rückmeldung darüber, dass die Frage gut formuliert ist. Auch das muss man ja u.U. erst mal lernen. Deshalb vote ich da auch dann leichter up, wenn mich die (gut gestellte) Frage nicht interessiert und ich keine Lust habe, sie zu beantworten.

Answer (score 3):

Mit dem Abstand einiger Jahre muss ich sagen, daß ich das Anliegen berechtigt finde. Fragen werden zu selten auf- und meiner Meinung nach auch zu häufig abgewertet.

Es erscheint mir durchaus als legitim, eine Frage deshalb aufzuwerten, weil sie interessante Antworten generiert. Diese Frage war dann gut für die Seite, auch wenn sie nicht unbedingt gut gestellt gewesen sein mag.

Auch scheinen manche bei der Bewertung von Fragen viel strengere Kriterien anzuwenden als bei der Bewertung von Antworten. Letztere bekommen Upvotes, auch wenn sie die Frage sehr kurz und oberflächlich abhandeln, während Fragesteller eher auf den Deckel kriegen.

Plädoyer: Über mehr Upvotes von Fragen **nachdenken**.

(Ergänzung: Vor allem bei neuen Postern fände ich es auch gut, wenn dem Downvote einer Frage ein Kommentar mit Verbesserungsvorschlägen oder Nachfragen voranginge. Man kann mit der Entscheidung für oder gegen Up- bzw. Downvote auch ein wenig warten.)

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist hinfällig, da sich 0 Punkte auch aus der Summe von Downvote eines Dritten und dem Upvote des Angeklagten ergeben können.

PS: Als Mod mit DB Zugang sieht man natürlich mehr Details. Das betrifft aber die wenigsten.

Wäre die Stimmabgabe Pflicht, wäre dies einfach im System zu verankern und sollte bereits umgesetzt sein, dann ggf. auch automatisch. Ist es das wegen netzwerkweiter Regeln aber nicht, hat dies vielleicht seinen Grund.

Entgegenstehende Gründe sind hier nicht ausreichend dargetan. Es mag verschiedenste Gründe für Vote-Verhalten geben. Soweit hier Bestimmbares nahegelegt wird, ist dies nur für jene verständlich, die es bereits nachvollziehen. Eigentlich ist der Aufruf eine Meinungsumfrage. Es wird suggeriert, es bestehe die Alternative zwischen Upvote oder Schließung. Das ist grausames Schwarz-Weiß-Denken. Ebenso ist meine Antwort eigentlich keine, sondern eine ablehnende Absage.

Und zwar würde man ggf. zu Upvotes für schlechte Fragen verleiten. Was eine schlechte Frage ist, ist zweifelhaft. Jedenfalls bedarf eine Frage noch nicht eines Upvotes der zu besserer Sichtbarkeit führt, nur weil die Frage den Anforderungen nach den Regeln genügt, nicht geschlossen oder gar gelöscht zu werden. Dennoch will die Frage beantwortet werden.

Übrigens hast du meine eben beantwortete Frage scheinbar auch nicht abgevotet; ich deine Antwort jedenfalls nicht, weil unbefriedigend; habe die Antwort dennoch akzeptiert, weil faktisch korrekt sowie angemessen und weil eine weitere Antwort kaum zu erwarten ist.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe - in seltenen Fällen - auch schon mal Fragen beantwortet aber bewusst nicht hochgewertet. Das waren dann Fälle, in denen beim Fragesteller ein Missverständnis vorlag. Da habe ich dann zwar den Fragesteller entsprechend aufgeklärt, aber wenn ich nicht der Ansicht war, dass dies ein naheliegendes Missverständnis sei, das viele Leute betreffen dürfte, kein Upvote gegeben.

Comment: Ja, eine vernünftige Ausnahme. Mein Begehr war es nicht Ausnahmesituationen zu sammeln, sondern Meinungen darüber, ob man, wenn man keine Ausnahme ausmacht, das Aufwerten durch Antwortende (Dritte) qua Kommentar ermuntert. Metadiskutanten sind für mich natürlich über jeden Verdacht erhaben.

Comment: @userunknown: Es sei mir der Hinweis gestattet, daß Du VolkerLandgrafs Stellungnahme zwar in Deinem Kommentar als "vernünftig" bezeichnest - und jemand anderer offenbar Deiner Meinung war, denn Dein Kommentar zeigt einen Upvote, dennoch aber weder Du noch Dein Upvoter sich dazu hinreißen ließen, Volkers Einlassung selbst eines Upvotes für würdig zu befinden. Möchtest Du Deine Argumente im Lichte Deiner Handlungen einer kritischen Würdigung unterziehen?

Comment: Ja, @bakunin. Ich habe die Antwort nicht aufgewertet, weil ich, wie im Kommentar dargelegt, nicht auf das Sammeln von Ausnahmen aus bin, in welchen Situationen eine Frage würdig ist, beantwortet zu werden, aber nicht würdig ist, aufgewertet zu werden. Ich meine, dass es der Normalfall sein sollte, dass man Fragen, die man beantwortet auch mit +1 belohnt. Es gibt natürlich viele begründbare Ausnahmen, das hier und da dann doch nicht zu tun, aber die Häufigkeit, in der die Auszeichnung unterbleibt, erklärt es nicht.