# Geht es hier überhaupt um die Sache?

Tags: discussion

Ich bin in einigen "Abteilungen" hier unterwegs und stelle fest, dass die deutsche Abteilung sich von anderen in zwei Punkten massiv unterscheidet:

-Downvotes ohne Begründund.

-Viele Upvotes für Antworten, die objektiv daneben sind.

Diskussionskultur aufgrund puren Interesses scheint nicht bekannt/gewollt zu sein. Wie viele Leute würden noch beitragen, wenn das Punktesystem wegfiele? Ganz wenige, schätze ich mal...

Comment: Kannst Du konkrete Beispiele dazu benennen? Zum Thema Diskussionskultur kann ich nur sagen, dass du derjenige bist, der sich da partout verwehrt hat.

Comment: Von dir erwarte ich auch keine Antwort, weil du genau diese Kategorie verkörperst! Downvotes, Unterstellungen etc. und auch noch nicht mal mutig genug, Gesicht zu zeigen!

Comment: Ich halte diese Feindseligkeit hier für absolut unangemessen.

Comment: Was du was für was hältst, ist mir egal! Nochmal: Du hast mir oft einen Downvote verpasst, weil meine Antwort nicht in die richtige Rubrik gehörte. Und ich bin Neuling. Dazu braucht man nichts zu sagen!

Comment: Das Downvote habe ich erklärt und auch, wie du damit umgehen kannst. Daher weiß ich nicht, was du meinst, mit *Downvotes, Unterstellungen etc. und auch noch nicht mal mutig genug, Gesicht zu zeigen!*.

Comment: "NO, I wouldn't unless the question is one that requires some massive mental effort."  Das war dein Kommentar auf den Hinweis, auch Fragen upzuvoten. So wie es in **allen** Abteilungen auf stackexchange üblich ist.

Comment: Unter der Betrachtungen der letzten Kommentardiskussionen mit dir und deines letzten Edits "Ps. Feiglinge mit downvotes, kommt raus und argumentiert! Danke! Mutig Flagge zeigen, gelle?", vote ich diese Frage als unerwünschten Rant zu closen.

Comment: Pass mal auf, du gehst deinen Weg und ich meinen, OK? Wenn du mal frustriert bist, kannste mich ruhig downgraden.

Comment: Vote whatever you want!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a rant in disguise.

Comment: "In disguise"? Why? Everything is transparent to everyone! You are confusing "ranting" with "liberty of expression"...

Comment: Und noch eins zum Schluss: Ich habe mal eine Frage gestellt zum Gebrauch von starken und schwachen Verben und du hast sie sofort blockiert und downvotet, weil meine Frage keine aussagekräftigen Ergebnisse zeitigen könnte deiner Meinung nach! Du beantwortest kaum Fragen, sondern du stänkerst meistens nur 'rum!

Comment: Ich habe nicht die Macht die Frage sofort zu blockieren. Dazu brauchen wir 5 Votes und du kannst alle Nutzer einsehen, die der gleichen Meinung waren die Frage zu schließen. Ich habe das ausreichend begründet. Dein letzter Satz ist einfach nur Unsinn und zeigt, dass Du hier etwas persönlich nimmst, was du nicht persönlich nehmen solltest. Lass es einfach bleiben.

Comment: Habe es doch schon oben geschrieben: Gehe deinen Weg!

Comment: Erstmal für Close bis der Eintrag umfassend überarbeitet und die aufgestellten Behauptungen unterfüttert wurden.

Comment: @Nico Gib doch bitte ein paar Beispiele für deine zwei genannten Punkte. Die sollten nicht allzu schwer zu finden sein.

Comment: Der Denkfehler ist meiner Meinung nach, daß es hier um Diskussionen ginge. Es geht um Fragen und Antworten. Up- und downvoten kann jeder, wie er möchte; wenn man das auf sinnvolle Weise tun möchte, gibt es genug Hinweise, nach denen man sich richten kann. Zu versuchen, ein anderes Mitglied von irgendetwas zu überzeugen, ist fehlgeleitet und führt nur ins Unglück.

Comment: @DavidVogt Das kann ich nur unterstreichen. Insbesondere den letzten Satz finde ich sehr wichtig zu bedenken.

Comment: Könnte mir jemand bitte kurz erklären, wie man aus der Gruppe austreten kann? Habe leider in "Help" keine Angaben dazu gefunden.

Comment: @DavidVogt Ich stimme dir prinzipiell zu, aber da Sprache keine Mathematik ist und jeder ein anderes Empfinden hat, lassen sich Diskussionen nicht vermeiden, was an und für sich auch zuträglich ist im Sinne von Austausch. "Zu versuchen, ein anderes Mitglied von irgendetwas zu überzeugen, ist fehlgeleitet und führt nur ins Unglück" habe ich nicht so ganz verstanden im diesem Kontext....

Comment: @Nico: Ich empfinde Kommentare wie `Pass mal auf` oder `Dazu braucht man nichts zu sagen!` als ziemlich aggressiv. Ich habe keinen idealen Weg, hier den Spiegel vorzuhalten um zu prüfen, ob Sie das auch als aggressiv empfinden, falls ich Ihnen so antworte. Vielleicht eine Rollenumkehr: alle Kommentare in eine Datei kopieren und die Autoren Nico und infinitezero vertauschen & nochmal durchlesen, falls das Gefühl besteht "ich gegen alle" dann auf alle ausdehnen. Falls Sie Ihre Reaktion "aus dem Mund eines anderen" als keineswegs aggressiv empfinden, geht mir die Idee aus, es zu verdeutlichen.

Comment: Sie sind durchaus berechtigt, Ihre Empfindungen zu äußern. Mir persönlich bringt das nichts, zumal ich bereits betont habe, dass ich mit dem o.g. User nicht mehr interagieren werde. Das ist ebenfalls mein gutes Recht. Ich bedauere auch, Sie enttäuschen zu müssen: "ich gegen alle" dann auf alle ausdehnen". Ich habe mit einigen Benutzern einen konstruktiven Dialog und wähne mich keineswegs als Opfer. Wo Ihre Inferenz herrührt, wissen nur Sie.  diesem Sinne... schönen Tag noch!

Comment: @ShegitBrahm "Pass mal auf" ist eine Redewendung, die -zumindest in NRW- auch bedeuten kann: "wir machen das so": "Pass mal auf, wir treffen uns morgen da".

Answer (score 3):

Ich halte deinen Post für gut und wichtig, weil er einiges über die Willkommenskultur aussagt, die nicht nur in diesem Forum seit einiger Zeit Thema ist. Wenn neue Leute in diesem Forum durch das Verhalten anderer, die schon länger dabei sind, so frustriert werden, dass sie das zum Thema auf Meta machen, sollten wir das m.E. nicht einfach vom Tisch wischen und als *rant in disguise* mittels close vote in der Versenkung verschwinden lassen, sondern darüber nachdenken, ob das hier nicht auch irgendwie Spaß machen soll.

Zu den vier von dir genannten Punkten:

1. Downvotes ohne Begründung

Es gibt keine Pflicht zur Begründung eines Downvotes. Es ist also jedem freigestellt, eine Begründung zu liefern oder eben nicht. Ich persönlich halte Downvotes ohne Begründung für kindisch und destruktiv. Sie helfen weder einem Lernenden, die Qualität einer Antwort einzuschätzen, noch helfen sie dem Autor der Antwort, eventuelle Mängel zu erkennen und ggf. die Antwort zu überarbeiten. Sie sind deshalb alles andere als förderlich für die Qualität, sondern höchstens geeignet, den Autor zu frustrieren.

Auf einer Plattform wie dieser finden sich aber - wie überall in allen Gesellschaften - die unterschiedlichsten Leute mit ihren jeweiligen Beweggründen, jeweils individuell ausgeprägtem Verantwortungsbewusstsein und nicht zu ergründenden Interessenlagen. Solange es keine Pflicht zur Begründung gibt, muss man darum wissen und damit leben.

Ich halte die freie, eigenverantwortliche Entscheidung für wesentlich angenehmer als ein eng geschnürtes Regelkorsett.

2. Viele Upvotes für Antworten, die objektiv daneben sind.

Das mag dir so erscheinen. Mir erscheint es auch manchmal so, als wenn die höchst bewertete Antwort nicht unbedingt die qualitativ höchstwertige ist und in manchen Fällen hege ich sogar den Verdacht, dass das Gegenteil der Fall ist. Allerdings ist das persönliche Einschätzung und ich denke, du liegst fasch damit, deine Einschätzung als *objektiv* anzusehen. Ansonsten gilt unter Punkt 1 Gesagtes hier ebenso. Ich bin auch selten mit den Wahlergebnissen zufrieden. Trotzdem halte ich die freie und geheime Wahl für äußerst wertvoll und kenne keine bessere Lösung. Das lässt sich auf die Situation hier vielleicht übertragen?

3. Diskussionskultur aufgrund puren Interesses scheint nicht bekannt/gewollt zu sein.

Richtig. Für Diskussionen gibt es Meta. Ansonsten geht es nur um Fragen und Antworten. Das kann man gut oder schlecht finden. Es ist einfach eine Setzung dieser Plattform. Mehr dazu in Punkt 4.

4. Wie viele Leute würden noch beitragen, wenn das Punktesystem wegfiele?

Das kann ich nicht einschätzen. Es gibt ja auch andere Foren, die ein solches Punktesystem nicht haben, die aber ausgiebig genutzt werden. Hier liegt aber eine Gefahr, der du m.E. nicht erliegen solltest. Dieses Punktesystem hat ja seinen Grund.

So ein Punktesystem nutzt in geschickter Weise die Anfälligkeit des inneren menschlichen Belohnungssystems. Einmal Blut geleckt, werden Menschen scharf auf diese nichtssagenden Zahlen. Damit kann man Leute dazu bringen, immer wieder auf diese Seite zu kommen, um sich eine kleine Belohnung für etwas abzuholen, das ohnehin in ihrem Interesse liegt. Vordergründig wird das als Qualitätssicherung verkauft. In gewisser Weise ist es dazu ja möglicherweise auch geeignet. Letztlich steht hinter allen Stackexchange Foren aber ein Unternehmen mit dem Ziel der Gewinnmaximierung und damit dem Ziel, so viele Nutzer wie möglich zu Beiträgen dieser Datensammlungen zu bewegen. Wenn du das Punktesystem unter diesem Gesichtspunkt betrachtest, fällt es dir vielleicht leichter, darauf weniger Wert zu legen und hier einfach nur deinem Interesse an der Sprache Futter zu geben.

Dieser Punkt spielt m.E. auch eine wichtige Rolle für die Einschätzung der ersten drei Punkte. Das Punkesystem wird sicher auch von einigen Leuten dazu benutzt, einen Mangel an Anerkennung und Einfluss im Alltag auszugleichen. Es würde mich sogar wundern, wenn das nicht vorkommen würde. Moralisch ist das nicht zu bewerten. Wir sind ja hier nicht in der Kirche. Es ist einfach normaler Durchschnitt menschlichen Verhaltens und richtet ja auch keinen wirklichen Schaden an, sofern man diese Votes nicht überbewertet.

Um abschließend die Frage zu beantworten:

> Geht es hier überhaupt um die Sache?

Das kannst du nur für dich selbst beantworten und bleibt letztlich jedem Nutzer selbst überlassen.

Ich hoffe, diese Antwort hilft dir dabei, deine Prioritäten auszuloten. Ich finde es sehr angenehm, wenn hier Leute mit wirklichem Interesse an der Sprache unterwegs sind und fände es sehr schade, wenn gerade solche Leute sich von dem m.E. zweitrangigen Votingsystem frustrieren lassen.

Comment: Differenzierte Antwort! Ein paar Anmerkungen. (1) Ich wollte mich nicht als Opfer darstellen. (2) Der Titel basiert lediglich auf meinen Erfahrungen. Generell agiert man in anderen Communities hier "menschlicher". Wenn jemand eine Antwort gibt, mit der man nicht einverstanden ist, wird dagegen argumentiert ohne Lawinen von Downvotes. (3) Das Wort "Diskussion" war nicht als "Antwort" gemeint, sondern als "Dialog" unter den Kommentaren.  (4) Wenn jeder weiß, wie das System funktioniert, warum kommen Aufforderungen vor a la: "consider upvoting this answer"?  Das empfinde ich als Bevormundung.

Comment: @Nico Ja, Bevormundung ist ein leidiges Thema. [Nervt mich auch](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1554/36196).

Comment: "[...] rant in disguise mittels close vote in der Versenkung verschwinden lassen [...]". Nach der massiven Anfeindung in den Kommentaren habe ich nichts anderes in diesem Beitrag erkennen können.