# Diese Frage hat 8 Antworten. Ist eine Community-Wiki sinnvoller?

Tags: discussion

Die Frage [Was ist ein Wort für eine Gruppe oder jemanden, von der oder dem man sagen würde, dass sie keine Chance in etwas haben?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69599/was-ist-ein-wort-f%c3%bcr-eine-gruppe-oder-jemanden-von-der-oder-dem-man-sagen-w%c3%bcrde) hat zurzeit 8 (acht!) Antworten (inkl. einer von mir). Ich denke hier bietet es sich, gerade im Zuge der Übersicht an, diese zu einer Community-Wiki (CW) Antwort zusammenzufügen. Ich bin mir allerdings nicht im Klaren darüber, wie die Policy von SE oder GermanSE ist, gerade da hier ja auch schon ein bisschen was an Reputation geflossen ist.
In meinen Augen wäre es am Dienlichsten bei einer Frage nach Ausdrücken/Formulierungen, die eine solche Breite an Antwortmöglichkeiten hat, diese immer in einer CW zusammenzufügen. Wie wird dies bisher gehandhabt? Gibt es überhaupt Handlungsbedarf?

Comment: Als Autor einer Antwort hätte ich kein Problem damit. Wenn du deine Antwort zum Community-Beitrag machst und meine Antwort integrierst, lösche ich meine Antwort. Ich denke, es würde die Lesbarkeit erhöhen, habe aber selbst keine Lust, mir die Arbeit zu machen, auch weil es da vielleicht zu Diskussionen mit den anderen Autor:innen kommen könnte... An sich find ich es aber eine gute Idee.

Answer (score 1):

In Anbetracht der gewaltigen Streubreite der Antworten, von denen viele nur einen speziellen Aspekt abdecken und einige bestenfalls umgangssprachliches Niveau erreichen, wäre da massiver Umarbeitungsaufwand nötig.

Ressourcen spart man nicht, weil gelöschte Antworten erhalten bleiben. Damit bleibt:

- einfacheres Konsumieren für künftige Nutzer, derer es (in Anbetracht einer einzigen Stimme für die Frage)  wohl auch nicht viele geben wird
- einfacheres Ergänzen neuer Vorschläge.

Meine Gesamteinschätzung: lohnt eher nicht

Comment: Dass die Frage bei 8 Antworten nur (m)ein Vote erhalten hat, [ist ein ganz anderer Punkt](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/diskrepanz-antwort-ohne-upvote-der-frage/1554#1554)