# Was für Details? (Der Streusel-Snack)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, editing, moderation

Ich habe nach der Herkunft eines Wortes gefragt (Streuselschnecke, [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69618/streusel-schnecke-oder-schneck)), wurde aber wegen Mangel an Klarheit und Detail geschlossen.

Dabei ist auf German.SE nicht ersichtlich, wer die Frage geschlossen hat. Dafür die Frage an die Allgemeinheit im Raum.

**Wo mangelt es da bitte an Details oder Klarheit?**

Leiht mir mal kurz euer Schweineohr.

Die Frage wurde meines erachtens aus Argwohn herabgewählt und geschlossen (nach Wählerschaft, automatisch oder offizieller Intervention), weil die Frage als Beleidigung empfunden wurde.

Ich unterstelle ziemlich offensichtlich – was die Gemüter erzürnt – dass die Streuselschnecke mit dem Snack verwandt sei, und insofern vermutlich eben nicht vom Schneckentier abstamme.

Die Hälfte der Streitbeteiligten versteht das schon irgendwie. Also brauchte man mir nicht vorwerfen, ich hätte mich undeutlich ausgedrückt. Ich hab das ja in einem Kommentar noch einmal nachdrücklich erklärt. Nur ignoriert jeder ein anderes x-beliebiges Detail, um sich zu einer kurzentschlossenen Antwort durchzuringen.

Die andere Hälfte versteht es schlicht nicht. Jedoch bin ich nicht hergekommen, um wieder einen ausuffernden, stundenlangen Vortrag an jemanden zu richten, der ...

Sei's drum. Ich habe versucht mich kurz halten.

Das war auch zweckmäßig, denn ich habe eben nicht explizit unterstellt, das Wort *Streuselschnecke* sei mit dem englischen Wort *Snäck* gebildet worden. Darauf zielt eine der Antworten leider ab, um danach auch noch frech zu werden, ohne sich eines besseren belehren zu lassen.

Die nächste Antwort bespricht lediglich, ob das bezeichnete Gebäck ohne Sprialform auskommt.

An dieser stelle irritiert mich ungemein, dass nicht ein einziger Nutzer aus der bevölkerungsreichsten deutschsprachigen Stadt dem wütenden Mob beschwichtigend entgegen steht.

Jene Antwort folgt einem recht offensichtlichen Muster, einen Kommentar als Antwort zu tarnen, in dem im Nachhinein eine aus der Luft gegriffene Behauptung aufgestellt wird, welche das Problem scheinbar lösen würde. Da die Behauptung jedoch nur durch den Kommentaranteil getragen wird, ist die Hypothese noch nicht entkräftet.

Zwar ist der Kommentar hilfreich. Darauf kann ich hier nicht groß eingehen. Im Englischen Wikipedia-Artikel, der bezeichnender Weise *Bread-roll* lautet, wenngleich auch dort keine Schneckenform erkennbar ist, finden sich nämlich dezente Hinweise auf Vergleichsmaterial was das Backwerk angeht.

***Das sind Fehlschlüsse, keine Details***

Es ist nicht meine Aufgabe, in der Frage allerlei Fehlschlüsse vorwegzunehmen. Der aufgeschlüsselte Kritikpunkt, "This question needs details or clarity", ist ohnehin kaum belastbar, weil die vorgegebenen Auswahlmöglichkeiten zur Anschuldigung derart begrenzt sind, dass meiner Erfahrung nach beliebiges darin gewählt wird, wenn es eigentlich nur darum geht, das Thema abzuschließen, oder unterschiedlich geurteilt wird (das sieht man, wenn man selbst eine Stimme zum close vote abgibt, sodass sich im Zweifelsfall eine Gruppe bildet, die dem Vorläufer nachgibt), weil die Gründe unscharf abgetrennt sind und gleichzeitig zutreffen können. "OP ist ein ..." wäre sogar ein möglicher Grund; einigt euch bitte darauf, wenn ihr es nicht besser wisst.

Deshalb und eventuell aus weiteren Gründen ist unter den Kommentaren und Kommentarantworten einiges Nachfragen zu finden, aber nichts, was auf einen Mangel an Details didekt hinweisen würde.

An notwendigen Details, soweit man mir die Kenntnis abverlangen kann, sind die entscheidenden doch allgemein bekannt. Denn die Herkunft der Worte *snack* bzw. *Schnack* im Englischen und Deutschen ist relativ unsicher. Auf Niederländisch bzw. Niederdeutsch kann man sich gerade noch so einigen. Diese Erkenntnis hilft der Fragestellung kaum weiter.

Für die Frage, "Was war zuerst da ...", müsste man sich zwangsläufig mit beiden auseinandergesetzt haben.

Demnach besteht bei der Gebäck-Schneck' die Erfordernis spezialisierten Wissens über Jargon, das einen entscheidenden Teil der Antwort ausmachen würde. Die Frage allein darauf auszurichten, wann etwa das Wort "Streuselschnecke" zuerst begegnet.

Es hilft auch nichts, wenn ich schlicht unterstelle, dass die Morphologie ([2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54733/whence-the-s-in-st%c3%b6psel)) oder Phonologie ([3](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58025/orthography-voiced-sonorant-after-short-vowel-dusselig)) eben auf gewisse Sprachzweige hindeuten mögen. Denn dahingehend bin ich mir ja nich so sicher, und dann folgen bald die Gegenfragen, wie ich denn überhaupt darauf komme. Dies zu beantworten ist wiederum ganz leicht. Es heißt halt nicht *niederes Deutsch*, aber einige scheinen es zu denken. Ohnehin wird dieser Themenbereich wegen der uneinheitlichen Schrift der Sprache einiges an Schwierigkeiten bereiten. Zum Themengebiet dieses Stacks gehört es dennoch.

**Also, wie soll man damit umgehen?**

Zuerstmal könnten all unsachlichen Kommentare gelöscht werden. Dafür fehlen mir die Credentials. Tatsächlich wurden schon aus den Kommentaren gelöscht, nämlich meiner, aber auch nur einer, aus welchem Ungrund auch immer.

Zwar ist der Frage meiner Ansicht nach nichts weiter hinzuzufügen. Ein ernsthaft begründeter Zweifel an der Aussage, "eine Streuselschnecke hat ja keine Schneckenform", wäre ernstzunehmen. Mir reinewegs Lüge zu unterstellen, das kann ich jedoch nicht ernst nehmen. Entsprechende Kommentare wurden nunmehr samt meiner Stellungnahmen gelöscht. Das betrifft nur das Symptom, nicht die Ursache.

Man darf ruhig annehmen, dass es sich in der Frage um einen Wortwitz handelt. Das bedeutet nicht, dass ich irgendwen damit angegriffen hätte. Die Frage unterstellt eben auch der Gebäckform, ein Witz zu sein, was ich angesichts Gesichtswurst und der gleichen nicht gänzlich abwegig finde. Darüber hinaus wäre ein Wortwitz im Bereich des Schnack, also im landläufigen Sinne, der dem Backwerk vorausgegangen sein könnte, durchaus angemessen, so wie bspw. *Kaffe* und *unterhaltsamer Nachmittag* synonym sind. Ob dies der Geschichtsschreibung vielleicht nicht mehr zugänglich ist, steht zu befürchten.

Es wäre hinzunehmen, wenn die Frage ohne Antwort verbleibt. Ich weiß all zu gut, wie es in den Fingern jucken kann. Dabei heißt es tatsächlich, *wer keine Ahnung hat, ...* und gerne einen Up-Vote da lassen. Siehe ähnlich die Aussage eines erfahrenen Nutzers ( @UserUnknown [https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/diskrepanz-antwort-ohne-upvote-der-frage/1556#1556]).

Deshalb noch mal die Frage, wie sollte mit sturen Nutzern umzugehen sein, die sich beleidigt fühlen und gegebenfalls sogar ausfällig werden: "Für einen sonst so in der (deutschen) Sprache bewanderten vectory", von jemandem der infinitezero heißt. Sprachnazitum: "Eine Streuselschnecke hat durchaus Schneckenform. Wenn sie die nicht hat, ist es [keine Streußelschnecke sondern] ein Streuseltaler", die Bäcker-Innung Süd incognito, wie ich vermute.

Was unangemessen ist, ist der Kurzschluss, es müsse glatt eine Schneckenform haben, weil es nunmal so heißt. Genau das stellt die Frage in der Frage in Frage. Damit umzugehen, wenn man nicht mit der Prämisse einverstanden ist, erfordert genau einen einzigen Kommentar. Jenen einzigsten Kommentar habe ich umgehend beantwortet, aber niemand sah sich befähigt, diesen warzunehmen.

Darf ich höflicher Weise fragen, warum?

Falls dieser Anlauf scheitert, stelle ich die Frage gerne in Kurzform mit der Konklusio aus dem letzten Absatz gerne nochmal.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn ich das richtig sehe, hat niemand deine Frage, dass *Schnecke* und *Snack* miteinander verwandt sein könnten, ernst genommen. Diese Frage wird allerdings auch verdunkelt dadurch, dass du sie daran festmachst, dass einige Streuselschnecken keine Schneckenform haben. Dieser Kontext macht unklar, was genau du eigentlich wissen wolltest.

Und dann ist die Diskussion ein bisschen eskaliert. Der von dir erwähnte Kommentar von infinitezero (*Für einen sonst so in der (deutschen) Sprache bewanderten vectory*) geht bereits unnötig ins Persönliche. Ich denke, deine Art, die Dinge dann zu behandeln (etwa *@TilmanSchmidt, willst du behaupten ich würde lügen?*), hat nicht geholfen, hier für Verständnis zu sorgen. Wenn ich das recht sehe, hat dir niemand explizit vorgeworfen, zu lügen. Das ist eine Interpretation / ein Schluss von dir, und er eskaliert die Situation weiter.

Um auf deine Frage zu antworten, wie du mit auf dich als Person abzielenden Kommentaren umgehen solltest: Du solltest den Kommentar oder die Antwort mit einer Flag versehen, sodass sie moderiert wird. Wenn deine Frage aufgrund eines Missverständnisses geschlossen wurde, kannst du hier auf Meta versuchen, das Missverständnis aufzuklären.

PS - Ich habe die ins Persönliche gehenden Kommentare von infinitezero und TilmanSchmidt unter der Frage nun gelöscht.

Comment: Ich würde zwar die Gesamtheit meiner Äußerungen als Teil meiner Persönlichkeit verstehen, insbesondere im textbasierten Internet. Ich muss nochmal klarstellen, dass es ganz unpersönlich um die Fragestellung und mögliche Antworten zum Thema geht, insbesondere im Sinne von *mögen*